# django how do I know which checkbox was checked

Tags: python, sql, django

my application is a restaurant's web site. One can order food. I am having trouble with this functionality.

I cannot figure out how to store the order in the DB.

models.py:

```
DRINK_TYPES = (
    (1, 'soft_drinks'),
    (2, 'drinks'),
    (3, 'wines'),
    (4, 'beer'),
    (5, 'juice'),
)

WINE_COLORS = (
    (1, 'white'),
    (2, 'rose'),
    (3, 'red'),
)

WINE_SWEETNESS = (
    (1, 'dry'),
    (2, 'sweet'),
    (3, 'semi-sweet'),
    (4, 'semi-dry'),
)

DRINK_VOLUME = (
    (1, 'by the glass'),
    (2, 'bottle'),
    (3, 'decanter'),
)

class Order(models.Model):
    name_surname = models.CharField(max_length=99, verbose_name='imię nazwisko')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=199, verbose_name='adres')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='numer telefonu')
    self_pickup = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='odbiór własny')
    dish = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, verbose_name='danie')
    drink = models.ManyToManyField(Drinks, verbose_name='napój')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name='wysłane')
    dish_order_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=' danie główne ilość', default=0)
    drink_order_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='drink ilość', default=0)
    wine_order_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='wino ilość', default=0)
    juice_order_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='sok ilość', default=0)
    beer_order_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='piwo ilość', default=0)

class Dish(models.Model):
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='danie')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, verbose_name='cena')
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)

class Drinks(models.Model):
    drink_type = models.IntegerField(choices=DRINK_TYPES, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='napoje typ')
    drink_volume = models.IntegerField(choices=DRINK_VOLUME, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='objętość')
    wine_colors = models.IntegerField(choices=WINE_COLORS, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='kolor wina')
    wine_sweetness = models.IntegerField(choices=WINE_SWEETNESS, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='smak wina')
    drink_name = models.CharField(max_length=99, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='napoje nazwa')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, default=0.00, verbose_name='cena')
```

class OrderView(View):

```
def post(self, request):
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new = Order.objects.create(
                                   dish_name=request.POST.get('dish_{{dish.id}}'),
                                   drink=request.POST.get('drink_{{drink.id}}'),
                                   name_surname=request.POST.get('name_surname'),
                                   address=request.POST.get('address'),
                                   email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                   phone_number=request.POST.get('phone_number'),
                                   self_pickup=request.POST.get('self_pickup')
                                   dish_order_quantity=request.POST.get('dish_order_quantity'),
                                   wine_order_quantity=request.POST.get('wine_order_quantity'),
                                   drink_order_quantity=request.POST.get('drink_order_quantity'),
                                   juice_order_quantity=request.POST.get('juice_order_quantity'),
                                   beer_order_quantity=request.POST.get('beer_order_quantity'),
                                   )
    return redirect('order')

def get(self, request):
    form = OrderForm
    dishes = Dish.objects.all()
    wines = Drinks.objects.filter(drink_type=3)
    beers = Drinks.objects.filter(drink_type=4)
    juices = Drinks.objects.filter(drink_type=5)
    soft_drinks = Drinks.objects.filter(drink_type=1)
    drinks = Drinks.objects.filter(drink_type=2)

    return render(request, 'order.html', {'dishes': dishes,
                                          'drinks': drinks,
                                          'wines': wines,
                                          'beers': beers,
                                          'juices': juices,
                                          'soft_drinks': soft_drinks,
                                          'form': form})
```

order.html:

```
<div class="extendables_bottom_margin">
    <form method="POST" id="order_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Dania główne</a>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% for dish in dishes %}
                {{ dish.dish_name }} ................. {{ dish.price }}
                <div class="menu_choice">
                  <input name="dish_{{dish.id}}" type="checkbox" class="inline"/>
                  <select name="dish_order_quantity" class="menu_choice_count" form="order_form">
                    <option value="--">--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </div><br>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Drinki</a>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% for drink in drinks %}
                {{ drink.drink_name }} ................. {{ drink.price }}
                <div class="menu_choice">
                  <input name="drink_{{drink.id}}" type="checkbox" class="inline"/>
                  <select name="drink_order_quantity" class="menu_choice_count" form="order_form">
                    <option value="--">--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </div><br>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3">Wina</a>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% for wine in wines %}
                {{ wine.drink_name }} / {{ wine.get_drink_volume_display }} ................. {{ wine.price }}
                <div class="menu_choice">
                  <input name="wine_{{drink.id}}" type="checkbox" class="inline"/>
                  <select name="wine_order_quantity" class="menu_choice_count" form="order_form">
                   <option value="--">--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </div><br>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4">Soki</a>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% for juice in juices %}
                {{ juice.drink_name }} ................. {{ juice.price }}
                <div class="menu_choice">
                  <input name="juice_{{drink.id}}" type="checkbox" class="inline"/>
                  <select name="juice_order_quantity" class="menu_choice_count" form="order_form">
                    <<option value="--">--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </div><br>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse5">Piwa</a>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% for beer in beers %}
                {{ beer.drink_name }} ................. {{ beer.price }}
                <div class="menu_choice">
                  <input name="beer_{{drink.id}}" type="checkbox" class="inline"/>
                  <select name="beer_order_quantity" class="menu_choice_count" form="order_form">
                    <option value="--">--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                </div><br>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <div class="cd">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="wyślij">
    </form>
  </div>
```

In my .html I have a loop printing individual dishes/beverages. Each loop has a radio-button and a drop down with quantity to order.

**1.** How do I save in DB when someone orders more than 1 main course or drink?
I think I will need to change my models but not sure how.

**2.** generally I cannot save in the DB even when I order 1 dish and drink and I cannot figure out the bug.

I appreciate all the input.

Thank you.

Comment: could you add the whole form in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

django can read the form data using `request.GET.get('input_name')` this will return the input value, 
if the check box was checked the value will be `True`

if you want to get the data from the select input do this :

**html code**

```
<select name = "myselect" class="menu_choice_count">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**django view**

```
choice = request.GET.get('myselect')
mymodel.objects.create(choice=choice...)
```

Comment: Yes, I will add that you must use beer.id for the value instead of what you have there

Comment: How do I pick up the check box value? choice = request.POST.get('beer_{{beer.id}}') ?

Which values exactly should be changed to beer.id?

I am really in the dark here.

Comment: bad syntax in your code *name=beer_{{beer.id}}* it should be *name="beer_{{beer.id}}"*

Comment: Hi, there still must be missing something. I do not see this data being pulled. I have a 'print' statement printing the keys, and the only keys I see are the customer details: name, email and so on. What else shall I provide? thank you

Comment: you cant do this with your code, you know I will make this project for you and then give you the link to GitHub because I want to help you contact me -mohammedalqudah@hotmail.com- : )